# How to join functions/listeners within a parent function

Tags: javascript, css, function, validation, listener

```
 How would I go about combining these scripts under one function/listener so that they do not interfere with one another.  The submit-button fadein/fadeout function should only fire if all inputs are valid or at least one input is invalid.
```

As the codes stand right now when they fire the fadein/fadeout for the review-submit-button, they break after the first firing any of the listeners toggling based upon individual input values instead of considering the states of all of the inputs.

```
 I am unsure of how to create a universal function that validates each input without using things such as 

$('#review-username')
```

I am also unsure where to begin figuring out how to apply specific validation effects to specific inputs(email vs username vs password).  Each script I wrote below works on their own, the problem is when all of the scripts are on the same page the review-submit-button fadein/fadeout effects break.

Validation Script 1

```
$('#review-username').on('input', function() {
           $('#review-username').addClass('review-invalid');     

        if (!/^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/g.test(this.value)) {       
          this.focus();
          return false; 
          this.setCustomValidity('Invalid Characters, Please Use Only AlphaNumeric Characters');
                $('#review-username').removeClass('review-valid'); 
           $('#review-username').addClass('review-invalid');        
        }

          if(this.value.length >= 5) {
            $('#review-submit-button').fadeIn(2250);   
        this.setCustomValidity('');
         $('#review-username').addClass('review-valid');
          $('#review-username').removeClass('review-invalid'); 
          $('#review-submit-button').removeClass('preventclick');
        }


     if(this.value.length < 5) {
$('#review-submit-button').fadeOut(1250);     
                $('#review-username').removeClass('review-valid'); 
           $('#review-username').addClass('review-invalid');
          $('#review-submit-button').addClass('preventclick');
        }


                  if(this.value.length > 16) {
                  $('#review-submit-button').fadeOut(1250);     
                $('#review-username').removeClass('review-valid'); 
           $('#review-username').addClass('review-invalid');
          $('#review-submit-button').addClass('preventclick');
        }

});
```

Validation Script 2

```
$('#review-jobtitle').on('keyup', function(k) {
    var val = $(this).val();
   if (val.match(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g)) {
       $(this).val(val.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g, ''));
   }
});


$('#review-jobtitle').on('input', function() {   
          $('#review-jobtitle').addClass('review-valid');  
 $('#review-jobtitle').addClass('invalid');
     if (!/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/g.test(this.value)) {
         $('#review-jobtitle').removeClass('review-invalid');
        $('#review-jobtitle').addClass('review-valid');
        }else{           

     if(this.value.length >= 3) {
$('#review-submit-button').fadeIn(2250);
  $('#review-jobtitle').removeClass('review-invalid');
 $('#review-jobtitle').addClass('review-valid');
            $('#review-submit-button').removeClass('preventclick');
          }else{
                    $('#review-jobtitle').removeClass('review-valid');
          $('#review-jobtitle').addClass('review-invalid');
          }
        }

     if(this.value.length < 3) {
$('#review-submit-button').fadeOut(1250);
                 $('#review-jobtitle').removeClass('review-valid');
 $('#review-jobtitle').addClass('review-invalid');
           $('#review-submit-button').addClass('preventclick');
        }else{
          $('#jreview-obtitle').removeClass('review-invalid');
 $('#review-jobtitle').addClass('review-valid');
        }

         if(this.value.length > 32) {
         $('#review-submit-button').fadeOut(1250);
                 $('#review-jobtitle').removeClass('review-valid');
 $('#review-jobtitle').addClass('review-invalid');
           $('#review-submit-button').addClass('preventclick');
        }
});
```

Validation Script 3

```
$('#review-email').on('input', function() {
  $('#review-email').addClass('review-invalid');     
     if(this.value.length >= 6) {

    var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;  
if(this.value.match(mailformat))  

 {  
$('#review-submit-button').fadeIn(2250);
  $('#review-email').removeClass('review-invalid');
 $('#review-email').addClass('review-valid');

 $('#review-submit-button').removeClass('preventclick');

}else{
$('#review-submit-button').fadeOut(1250);
  $('#review-email').removeClass('review-valid');
 $('#review-email').addClass('review-invalid');

 $('#review-submit-button').addClass('preventclick');
}

        }

     if(this.value.length < 6) {
$('#review-submit-button').fadeOut(1250);
  $('#review-email').removeClass('review-valid');
 $('#review-email').addClass('invalid');

 $('#review-submit-button').addClass('preventclick');
        }
           if(this.value.length > 64) {
           $('#review-submit-button').fadeOut(1250);
  $('#review-email').removeClass('review-valid');
 $('#review-email').addClass('review-invalid');

 $('#review-submit-button').addClass('preventclick');
        }
});
```

Comment: Can you make an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an additional function that determines the state of the submit button, and call it from the individual handlers.

```
function determineButtonState(){
    var bothInputsAreValid = // logic for validation
    if(bothInputsAreValid) // handle case for valid inputs
    else // handle case for invalid inputs
}

$('#review-email').on('input', function() {
    ...
    determineButtonState()
})
```

This is a good approach, in general. Refactor common chunks of code into a single, reusable source. I'm not going to scrub all of your code and tell you exactly what needs to be done, but this approach should get you what you need.